# Database browsing and updating using php

Tags: php

Using PHP I have developed an application that scores a salesman for every business he brings in. Now a new client will register in the application and create login details, he will then get a reference number, using the reference number he will then link himself to the mainhost who recruited him. My linking table is something like this :

memberref, subs_level, activedate, status and mainhost.

Each salesman is supposed to bring in three clients, he is then promoted to a new level, each time a new client register I populate the relevant table (activelnk) in this manner:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO activelnk (memberref, subs_level, activedate, status, mainhost, subposition)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
          if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql)){
       // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssd", $memberref, $subs_level, $activedate, $status, $mainhost, $subposition);
       // Set parameters
          $memberref = $refno;  
          $subs_level = 1;
          $activedate = date("Ymd");
          $status = "Active";
          $mainhost = $mainhost;
          $subposition = '1';   
    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
         if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
   // Put one unit to the mainhost
     if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
         $sql = "UPDATE activelnk SET subs_level=subs_level+1 WHERE mainhost='$mainhost'";
         if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {        
        echo "Record linked successfully here<br>";
```

My challenge is this, say the mainhost registers under him ten levels. Remember each time a new client is registered, the registrar becomes a mainhost and he has to earn a unit also one above has to earn a point up to the beginning of these processes. How do I make the code I have to cater a unit for each host from the end to the beginning. Hope someone can help here.

Comment: Make a trigger instead of a stored procedure. Trigger on new client registrations and just increment the x members a certain salesmen has registered. On a side node, how is this question getting 2 upvotes so fast. The question was lowquality at best

Comment: "`linking table is something like this`" - rather than "something like", it would be better if you use the MySql command `DESCRIBE <table>;` and show us it exactly

Comment: Thanks Mawg for your input, this is how my table looks.......................TABLE ACTIVELNK
(
  MEMBERREF REFNO NOT NULL,
  SUBS_LEVEL INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ACTIVEDATE TIMESTAMP,
  STATUS CREATEVARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
  MAINHOST REFNO NOT NULL,
  SUBPOSITION INTEGER NOT NULL
);